# Jenkins Triggering of a Build Step/Stage(not the entire job) at a given interval

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am trying to build a pipeline where i would need to chain multiple jobs and some of them has to start at a certain time.

Ex: Job1(starts at Midnight) -> Job2 -> Job3 ->Job4(starts at 4 PM)

Using Declarative Syntax:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('Fetch Latest Code-1') { 
            steps{
                build job: 'Get Latest - All Nodes', quietPeriod: 60
            }        
        }
        stage('CI Day - 1') {
            parallel {
                stage('ANZ CI'){
                    steps{
                        build job: 'ANZ - CI', quietPeriod: 120    
                    }
                }
                stage('BRZ CI'){
                    steps{
                        build job: 'BRZ_CI', quietPeriod: 120
                    }
                }
                stage('NAM CI'){
                    steps{
                        build job: 'NAM - CI', quietPeriod: 120    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('BEP Part 2') { 
            steps{
                build job: 'BEP_CI_Verification_Job', quietPeriod: 180
            }        
        }
        stage('Intermediate Results') {
            steps{
                build job: 'CI Automation Results', parameters: [string(name: 'Files', value: '_CI_')], quietPeriod: 300
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

As I create this job, I had configured the Job to start at 12 Midnight. Therefore, the 1st job automatically gets started at midnight. 
[image]

But, I would also need the second job(CI Day - 1) to begin at 1 AM & the last Job 'Intermediate results' to start at 6 PM.

As these jobs are Multi-Configuration Jobs(already tried setting them individually at the desired timings but they get overwritten when called through pipeline).

Also, did try triggers{ cron(0 1 * * 6) } within the stage/steps. No luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick idea for launching another job at a given time of day. Using Groovy code, calculate the difference in seconds between the desired launch time and the current time and use it as argument for the `quietPeriod` parameter.

If you get an error "Scripts not permitted to use method", you have to approve the methods using "Manage Jenkins" > "In-process script approval".

```groovy
import groovy.time.*

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('Stage 1') { 
            steps{
                script {
                    def secs = secondsUntil hourOfDay: 15, minute: 30, second: 0
                    echo "anotherjob will be triggered in $secs seconds"

                    build job: 'anotherjob', quietPeriod: secs
                }
            }        
        }
    }
}

long secondsUntil( Map dateProperties ) {
    def now = new Date()
    def to = now.clone()
    to.set( dateProperties )
    long duration = TimeCategory.minus( to, now ).toMilliseconds() / 1000
    return duration > 0 ? duration : 0
}
```