# Can a Jenkins pipeline invoke two different job with two different schedules?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Can I have two different Jenkins jobs with two different schedules , both the jobs needs to run from a pipeline via build job but should not do anything if they are not running as part of their individual schedule. Is this possible ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins Triggering of a Build Step/Stage(not the entire job) at a given interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59218698/jenkins-triggering-of-a-build-step-stagenot-the-entire-job-at-a-given-interval)

Comment: @zett42 Apparently no .. I want to have two different schedules in the same pipeline for two different jobs , not something based on timer ... the other link has one schedule and kick starts another job based on a timer ..

Comment: I still don't really understand, maybe you can clarify with a code sample?